# Android - Draw lines with Gradient

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, gradient, lines

I drawing a lines from point to point with gradient. To everything looks nice I using rounded caps between them. Problem is that caps are only in one colour. There is possibility to paint them separately or force drawing to do it right?

Or maybe just draw a dot between them?

[image]

I found solution.
Like I write before I just gonna draw my own Points between the lines and put there whatever colour I need.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `GradientDrawable` with the `LINE` shape,

Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html